# How to change denied/granted permission in Android M?

Tags: android, permissions

How can I give the user a chance to change his permissions in the App, 
which he has already set to granted/denied?

Let's say a user denied a permission. Later he want's to grant this permission.
Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: If user will select show never then he/she needs to change it from settings only otherwise we can apply code to check for permission everytime user reaches on that activity

Comment: The mechanism is same; You should store the permission which was denied and you should ask with the same method.

Comment: When you are performing some action which requires **PERMISSION** at that time you have to check for that permission either user has granted that permission or not. If **not** at that time you have to ask for that permission again. Untill user grants that permission, user not able to perform that specific task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case user has denied the permission you can check for the permission and if he also has checked never show again, in that case you can open your own dialog explaining the need of that permission for your app and from that dialog you can take the user to the app settings where he can allow the permission if he wanted.

```
public static void checkPermissionForExternalStorage(final Context mContext) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

        int writeExternalStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (writeExternalStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS_FOR_STORAGE);
            return;
        }

        //Do your stuff

    } else {

       //Do your stuff
    }
}



 public static void startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(Context mContext) {

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + mContext.getPackageName()));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    mContext.startActivity(i);
}



   @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {



        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS_FOR_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Do your stuff
            } else {
                // Permission Denied

                if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    showMessageOKCancel("The app was not allowed to write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission. Tap Settings > Permissions, and turn Storage on.",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    startInstalledAppDetailsActivity((Activity) mContext);
                                }
                            });
                }


                Toast.makeText( mContext, "Write to external storage permission request denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice it works now. Thanks! Wow I see you added code. This is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You show user a dialog asking to go to application settings and change the permission there, you have to motivate him somehow, tell why you need the permission. And you put an "Open settings" buton which triggers following function:

```
private void startInstalledAppDetailsActivity() {
    final Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are looking for:

1. You can create a separate View/Fragment just for this purpose enlisting all of the permissions that your app requires, from there you can call `requestPermission()`.
2. Or you can simply prompt user for permission whenever user opens the segment of the app that requires permission to run by calling `requestPermission()`.
3. User can also grant permission to the app from `Settings`. So It might be a good idea to direct user (via a dialog for instance) to change permission at a later time if he so wishes from `Settings`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

There is callback if `onRequestPermissionsResult` in which you get to know if user has granted permission or not. If user has not granted permission you can again request for the same whenever required.

Comment: @lodox My answer was same as the answer which you have accepted. But I purposely didn't put any code for your learning. But that's ok if you expect spoon feeding. Good luck