# How do i use WRITE_SETTINGS in android 5.1 higher version?

Tags: android, permissions, settings

I've developed a app which will automatically create hotsopt when app is opened
The app is working fine in android version 5.1 and below, when i'm trying to install app in android version 6.1 app wasn't showing the permissions which requires and after installing the app, app wasn't opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to ask for the required runtime permissions

For reference
[How to change denied/granted permission in Android M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510851/how-to-change-denied-granted-permission-in-android-m/39510984#39510984)

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.